# PDF page numbers in iPhone?

Tags: ios, pdf, webview, indexing

I have opened a PDF in webview.My PDF contains chapters in it.
But My first view is an index page.On Index page All chapter Names are there.
Now how can I go on a particular Chapter when selected from Index page i.e from first view.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thank you every one for your time

Comment: So the index is just text, not PDF links?

Comment: Yes I want link that index page to the PDF.My pdf include chapters in it.I want to do like this that if first chapter selected then need to open that chapter in pdf .

Comment: And can you edit the PDF when it's created?

Comment: Edit the PDF means ?? My PDF shows chapters in it ..Like first page first chapter and so on..

Comment: If the PDF doesn't contain links, how are you going to find where to link from and to? Text processing?

Comment: if you are always showing the same pdf, then first open that pdf in adobe acrobat or some pdf editor, and add the hyper-links there.Now save the pdf and use it in webView.